# delphi sql count to variable

Tags: sql, delphi

I'm new to this sort of thing. I am doing a school project and need to be able to get a count result from sql to a variable. I am using an ADOQuery to access the database.

The code used for the count is:

```
qryDatabase.SQL.Text := 'COUNT * FROM tblKandidate';
```

but I don't know how to assign this value to an Integer variable. Pls. try to stick to the basics as I am not very experienced yet.

Thank you, Robin

Comment: `qryDatabase.SQL.Text := 'SELECT COUNT * FROM tblKandidate'; qryDatabase.Open; ShowMessage(IntToStr(qryDatabase.Fields[0].AsInteger));`. But you might find this through the web search. You would find links [`like this`](http://www.delphipages.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-91972.html) for instance.

Comment: @TLama you should post this as an answer

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand this in a previous post that I read but now I understand.